# IBM ServeRAID M5015 how do I view info from Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, ibm, sata

I have an IBM x3620 M3 server that has

```
root@web26:~# lshw -short
/0/100/9/0 scsi4 storage LSI MegaSAS 9260
/0/100/9/0/2.0.0 /dev/sda disk 1990GB ServeRAID M5015
```

hardware raid controller.

How do I view the RAID array status, SMART status and issue rebuild commands from Ubuntu for it?

PS.

```
root@web26:~# modinfo mptctl
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-28-server/kernel/drivers/message/fusion/mptctl.ko
version:        3.04.12
license:        GPL
description:    Fusion MPT misc device (ioctl) driver
author:         LSI Corporation
srcversion:     9052501D1B37F5BF2F73C49
depends:        mptbase
vermagic:       2.6.32-28-server SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to install the [MegaCLI package](http://www.lsi.com/lookup/License.aspx?url=/DistributionSystem/User/AssetMgr.aspx?asset=56682&prodName=MegaRAID%20SAS%209261-8i&subType=Miscellaneous&locale=EN) from LSI. The UI is rather complicated; you would do well to look around the web for cheat sheets and summaries.

Comment: @justarobet : Thank you, that worked! I am posting more detailed instruction below:

Answer (score 5):

That did it, thank you @justarobert. Here are the detailed instructions for the future:

```
# cat /etc/issue
```

Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS \n \l

install two packages:

```
#apt-get install unzip rpm2cpio
```

unzip everything

```
#unzip 8.00.46_Linux_MegaCLI.zip
#unzip -d MegaCliLin MegaCliLin.zip
#unzip -d 8.00.46_Linux_MegaCLI 8.00.46_Linux_MegaCLI.zip
```

unpack RPMs (make sure you are in the right directory)

```
#rpm2cpio MegaCli-8.00.46-1.i386.rpm | cpio -idmv
#rpm2cpio Lib_Utils-1.00-08.noarch.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

(libsysfs.so.2.0.2 is required library, it comes from LSI in Lib_Utils-1.00-08.noarch.rpm,  apt-get install libsysfs did not do it for me):

```
#cp opt/lsi/3rdpartylibs/x86_64/libsysfs.so.2.0.2 /usr/lib64/
#cp ./opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64  /usr/local/sbin/
#ln -s /usr/local/sbin/MegaCli64 /usr/local/sbin/MegaCli
```

and voila, check RAID!

```
#  MegaCli -LDInfo -Lall -aALL
Adapter 0 -- Virtual Drive Information:
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 1.809 TB
**State               : Optimal**
Strip Size          : 128 KB
Number Of Drives    : 2
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAheadNone, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAheadNone, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Access Policy       : Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Disabled
Encryption Type     : None
Default Power Savings Policy: Controller Defined
Current Power Savings Policy: None
Can spin up in 1 minute: Yes
LD has drives that support T10 power conditions: No
LD's IO profile supports MAX power savings with cached writes: No
```

Answer (score 3):

An update for the latest MegaCLI:

Get your packages. For example, the MegaRAID SAS9280-16i4e:

```
http://www.lsi.com/products/storagecomponents/Pages/MegaRAIDSAS9280-16i4e.aspx
-> Support & Downloads -> Management Tools
```

Install two packages:

```
  #sudo apt-get install unzip rpm2cpio
or
  #sudo apt-get install unzip alien #...overkill, but some nice utils
```

Unzip everything:

```
#cd to/your/dir/containing/8.02.16_MegaCLI
#unzip -d 8.02.16_Linux_MegaCLI 8.02.16_Linux_MegaCLI.zip
#cd 8.02.16_Linux_MegaCLI/LINUX
#unzip -d MegaCliLin MegaCliLin.zip
```

Unpack RPMs:

```
#cd MegaCliLin
#rpm2cpio MegaCli-8.02.16-1.i386.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

The library libsysfs.so.2.0.2 is "required".  However, you may alternately use a native Ubuntu version with a soft link to fake out MegaCli:

```
  #rpm2cpio Lib_Utils-1.00-09.noarch.rpm | cpio -idmv
  #sudo cp opt/lsi/3rdpartylibs/x86_64/libsysfs.so.2.0.2 /usr/lib64/
or
  #sudo apt-get install libsysfs
  #locate libsysfs #...to get the proper filename
  #sudo ln -s /lib/libsysfs.so.2.0.1 /usr/lib64/libsysfs.so.2.0.2

#sudo cp opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 /usr/local/sbin/
#sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/MegaCli64 /usr/local/sbin/MegaCli
```

Check it, yo!

```
#sudo MegaCli -AdpAllInfo -aALL
#sudo MegaCli -LDInfo -Lall -aALL
#sudo MegaCli -PDList -aALL
```

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 10.04. The zip file seems to be named 8.02.16_MegaCLI.zip, and the libsysfs package name is libsysfs2.